# Autocmd event for `autoread`?

Tags: autocmd, autoload

I've just developed a nice solution for [automatically loading external changes made to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383044/143394), but I'd like a more obvious notification when [`autoread`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autoread%27) changes my buffer.

Is there a way of having a warning text appear (eg coloured red) when `autoread` triggers, so I can easily notice any changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to create a highlighted message is this:

```
echohl WarningMsg | echo "Buffer changed!" | echohl None
```

The first command selects a particular highlight mode for any subsequent `echo` calls. When `echo` is called the message will be displayed on the status line with approriate color and/or format (in my case white on yellow text). Don't forget the second `echohl` to return to regular highlighting.

Now I believe you want to display this when autoread is triggered. I am having success with this autocommand:

```
autocmd FileChangedShellPost *
  \ echohl WarningMsg | echo "Buffer changed!" | echohl None
```

I do `set autoread` in my vimrc, load a file with gvim, load it with another editor and change something, come back to gvim. Voila, I get the highlighted message.

Comment: That text style is what I'm after... but it's an event, not a script... see the link added to `autoread` in the question.

Comment: You might be able to use event `FileChangedShell`. `:h E321` implies that this event is associated with autoread.

Comment: Actually FileChangedShellPost is working for me. Updating my answer.